# RCA output of Pi in black and white

Tags: video, config.txt

I got a Pi recently, and when trying to use the RCA socket, only got a black and white picture on the TV, it's also blurred.

I changed my config.txt to have sdtv_mode set to 2 (PAL, I'm in the UK), and that didn't solve the issue. I don't have HDMI plugged in either, although I can use HDMI, I'm trying to get a small portable monitor, but those only accept RCA.

Comment: Pi2?  Have you got the correct type of plug?

Comment: @joan I have a Pi2 and the cable I'm using has the correct pin out.